# AWS-cli ec2 describe instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

i am digging on aws cli and from past 5 hours i struggling with 2 cli commands

1. i should get InstanceId, Name(this is a tag value) and specific tag value by providing its key ( including not tags given i.e NULL)
2. I should get InstanceId, Name and specific tag value by providing its key ( excluding NULL tags)

i got 50% of the answer for the 1 Question & 2 Question 0%

My cli command:

> aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'jsondata[ ].Instances[
>   ].[InstanceId, [Tags[?keys='Name'].Value] [0][0]' --output table`

```
           Ex: {

  "Jsondata" : [
                 { "Instances" : "i-xxxxxx",

                   "Tags":[

                  { "valve":" testserver",
                      "key": "server"
                   },
                 { "valve":" elb",
                    "key": "Name"
                  }
                ]
                },
             { "Instances" : "i-yyyyyy",

              "Tags":[

                    { "valve": " ",
                       "key": " "
                     },
                 { "valve":" elb2",
                      "key": "Name"
                    }
                      ]
                   }
                ]`
```

Thanks in advance. Please help me i need to sleep

Comment: let me guess...you are already having the data in JSON format and want to retrieve InstanceID, Tag Name using the Tag Value? or Do you want to retrieve data directly using AWS CLI?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So that we can help you get some sleep, could you please update your Question to clarify what results you wish from the commands? For example, what do you mean "specific tag value by providing its key ( including not tags given i.e NULL)"? If there is a tag of "Department", do you wish to display its value? What do you mean by "not tags given"?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To describe all instances with Tag "NAME" Use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag-key,Values=Name"
```

or

This Gives InstanceId with Particular Tag "Name"

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId, Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[0]]'
```

or

This Gives InstanceId with Particular Tag "Name" and Value of Tag

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId, Tags[?Key==`Name`], Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]]'
```

To describe all instances with Tag "Purpose" and its value as "test" Use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Purpose,Values=test"
```

If you already know the Instance id:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

To find every instance which doesn't contain a tag named "Purpose":

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: "Purpose"} ]}) | not)'
```

To filter against the value of the tag, instead of the name of the tag:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: "Name"}, {Value: "testbox1"}]}) | not)'
```

To find every instance which doesn't contain a tag:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: ""}, {Value: ""}]}) | not)'
```

Comment: aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=instance_name" | jq .Reservations[0].Instances[0].InstanceId

Comment: For anyone that doesn't know what jq is, it's a command line json parsing utility that is super handy in situations like this.  You can find it here: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Comment: is there any way i can filter if tag value is not  equal to some value?

Comment: @Ankit: This answer by Ali seems to explain how to find every instance which doesn't contain a tag named "Purpose" in the third-to-last chunk of code. Perhaps that helps?

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find that in AWS documentation